# iOS "RKObjectManager.h" not Found

Tags: ios, configuration, cocoapods, restkit

I am running Xcode Version 7.3 (7D175) and wanted to try out Restkit for ios. 
So I began following [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/58682/introduction-restkit-tutorial) tutorial. I came to this part:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ pod setup
$ cd /path/to/CoffeeKit
$ touch Podfile
$ [edit] Podfile (using your preferred editor; vim, nano, etc)
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

then I ran pod install. On some problems and googling , I updated to a newer version of cocoapods , and now my pod file looks like

```
target "Reminder" do
    platform :ios, '9.3'
    pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
end
```

Now when I tried to build my project I get the error:

```
\'RKObjectManager.h' file not found
```

[Stack overflow has this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33240398/2670775)

I tried adding whatever was mentioned in the header search path , but it doesn't fix it. I am an iOS newbie , so sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not related to RestKit itself but to related to Build setting /cocoapods that cannot find header files:

I resolved this exact similar issue by adding:

"${PROJECT_DIR}/Pods" recursive

to : "Build Settings" / "User Header Search Paths" setting.

Here is a link to stackoverflow you will find many alternatives that may fix your issue.

[iOS - Build fails with CocoaPods cannot find header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files)

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.