# Getting RestKit to work with CococaPods 1.x

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking, restkit

As we all know, when using RestKit in an iOS project utilizing CococaPods, we need to stick with the old CocoaPods 0.38 version. Otherwise RestKit won't link correctly: [RKObjectMapping.h Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562446/rkobjectmapping-h-not-found)

But now that CocoaPods is out of beta, we're forced to upgrade to CocoaPods 1.x because old versions are not able to update to the latest pod repository.

This causes the mentioned RestKit hell all over again.

How can we use RestKit with the new 1.x versions of CocoaPods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - the thread on this issue is huge: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2356

TL;DR:

The solution is simply to upgrade to RestKit 0.27.0

```
pod 'RestKit', '0.27.0'
```

But this might raise issues if your project explicitely references AFNetworking outside of RestKit. In this case, and since RestKit 0.27 is bundled with AFNetworking 1.3, we need to add:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.4'
```

Happy coding!